# Berry phase: Spin in a magnetic field parameter space manifold

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, group-theory, topology, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Canonical example for Abelian Bery phase is a spin in a magnetic filed, [e.g.](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/one.pdf). Usually authors calculate spin eigenstates, conclude that they don't depend on **B** in spherical components and so deduce that the sphere $S^2$ is the parameter space manifold. First question - shouldn't the parameter space actually be $S^2 \times (0,\infty) \cong B^2/O$, with $O$ being a ball center, as |**B**|  $\in (0,\infty)$?

I would like to obtain more a priori understanding of the parameter space manifold identification. Working in Cartesian coordinates, for example, this $S^2$ identification is not transparent. My reasoning is along these lines - Fixing |**B**| one would naively first conclude that the $SO(3)$ is actually this manifold as we can orient **B** as we wish. However, we should ''subtract'' rotations around **B** and so we are lead to the coset manifold $SO(3)/SO(2)\cong S^2$. Letting |**B**| change, we finally arrive at $B^2/O$. Is this correct reasoning? Thing that puzzles me here is that we have spins here so $SU(2)$ should be more appropriate but how do we arrive to $S^2$ then?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the active parameter space is $S^2$ rather than the whole three dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^3$ or the ball $B^3$ is that the Berry curvature depends solely on the projector $P$ over the eigenspace, for example, an Abelian Berry curvature can be expressed as
$$F = \mathrm{Tr}(P dP \wedge dP)$$
Now, spaces of  projectors over one dimensional subspaces are projective spaces (which $S^2$ is a partiular case of): For two dimensional Hamiltonians, the projector on any one dimensional subspace can be casted in the form:

$$P(z, \bar{z}) = \frac{1}{1+\bar{z}z}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & z\\ 
\bar{z} & \bar{z}z
\end{bmatrix}$$
with
$$z = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}$$
and $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the coordinates parametrizing a unit sphere $S^2$.
which is the one-(complex) dimensional projective space $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

This result generalizes as follows:

In fermionic time revesal invariant systems, the projectors are quaternionic valued and in the case of projectors on a one dimensional supspace (Abelian Berry phase), the parameter space is the one dimensional quaternionic projective space which is isomorphic to the four sphere:

$$\mathbb{HP}^1 \cong S^4$$

Please see for example: [Avron,  Sadun, Segert and Simon](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Barry_Simon2/publication/38330529_Chern_numbers_quaternions_and_Berry%27s_phases_in_Fermi_systems/links/02e7e52b388a0cc2a4000000/Chern-numbers-quaternions-and-Berrys-phases-in-Fermi-systems.pdf), where they obtain this parameter space as the parameter space of quadrupoles.

Another generalization is the case of the non-Abelian Wilczek-Zee phases, in this case the projectors are over higher dimensional subspaces of degenerate eigenvalues. Here, the parameter space is the Grassmann manifold:

$$\mathrm{Gr}(m,n) = U(m+n)/U(m)\times U(n)$$

where $m$ is the dimension of the Hamiltonian and $n$ is the dimension of the degenerate subspace of eigenvalues. Please see, for example, the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301140v2)  by Karle and Pachos.